# How to sum all values in NSMutableDictionary with the same key?

Tags: objective-c, collections, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary in my objective c class with different pair keys values.

```
({Name=John; date=20070506; type=5; value= 125;}, 
{Name=Tracy; date=20040506; type=2; value = 237; },
{Name=Tracy; date=20040506; type=5; value = 124; },
...)
```

I can sum all values with the next code, but I can't get this in the same object in NSMutableDictionary.

```
NSNumber *amountSum = [CATransaction valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"];
```

How could I sum the values for all objects with the same type and show this like one unique object? For example:

```
({Name=John; date=20070506; type=5; value= 249;}, 
{Name=Tracy; date=20040506; type=2; value = 237; },
...)
```

Could I use a collection operator like this: [Collections operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)  to do this??

thanks!

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried?

Comment: NSNumber *amountSum = [CATransaction valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"]; And I get the sum, but could I reagroup this in only one object in my NSMutable dictionary? I have edit my question bad writed.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get all the values for that valueForKey, so [Yourarray valueForKey:@"keyName"] will give you each value and finally you can loop over and sum all the values in array.

```
int total=0;
NSMutableDictionary *yourMutableDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (;;)
{
    int value=[[Yourarray objectAtindex:i] valueForKey:@"keyName"];
    total=total+value;
}

[yourMutableDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:total] forKey:@"mySUM"];

NSLog(@"%@",[yourMutableDict objectForKey:@"mySUM"]);
```

Comment: But how can I add this sum into the NSMutableDictionary directly? with the format that I show in my question then "For example:"? thanks!

Comment: Did it help you ?